# call method async inside Task.Run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, async-await, task-parallel-library

the code shown below is executed inside an asp.net mvc application

```
public async Task<string> GetCustomers1(){
    return await getcustomer1Async();
}
public async Task<string> GetCustomers2(){
    return await getcustomer2Async();
}
public async Task<JsonResult> Index(){
   var result1 =Task.Run(()=>GetCustomers1());
   var result2 =Task.Run(()=>GetCustomers2());
   Task.WaitAll(result1,result2);

}
```

I am clear that task run will create two threads to execute methods GetCustomers1, GetCustomers2.
 - my question is when the method GetCustomers1 and GetCustomers2 reach the line that has the word await, should the incomplete task be returned, where should the incomplete task be returned? Does the thread return to the thread pool?
-Task.WaitAll would you have the main thread busy until the other tasks finish running?

I know you shouldn't use tak.run if the method is asynchronous. But I want to know how the code works internally in such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am clear that task run will create two threads to execute methods GetCustomers1, GetCustomers2.

`Task.Run` doesn't create threads. It queues work to the thread pool.

> my question is when the method GetCustomers1 and GetCustomers2 reach the line that has the word await, should the incomplete task be returned, where should the incomplete task be returned? Does the thread return to the thread pool?

Yes, the thread is returned to the thread pool. When the `await` is ready to resume execution, the "continuation" of that method is queued to the thread pool. Note that continuations may or may not run on the same thread; they can run on any thread pool thread.

> Task.WaitAll would you have the main thread busy until the other tasks finish running?

Yes, that is what `Task.WaitAll` will do. It also blocks on asynchronous code, which is not a good idea. It's better to go [async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

> I know you shouldn't use tak.run if the method is asynchronous.

Using `Task.Run` for asynchronous code is fine. But in the general case, you shouldn't use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET because it queues work to the thread pool instead of letting ASP.NET have full control of the thread pool. Instead, call the asynchronous code directly and use asynchronous code (`Task.WhenAll`) instead of blocking code (`Task.WaitAll`):

```
public async Task<string> GetCustomers1() {
  return await getcustomer1Async();
}
public async Task<string> GetCustomers2(){
  return await getcustomer2Async();
}
public async Task<JsonResult> Index(){
  var result1 = GetCustomers1();
  var result2 = GetCustomers2();
  await Task.WhenAll(result1, result2);
}
```

Comment: (1/2) hi stephen Task.Run doesn't create threads. It queues work to the thread pool
what do you mean with that? 
Does the Run method queue the code to run on a different thread?

Comment: (2/2) code (Task.WhenAll) instead of blocking code (Task.WaitAll): example var a = await ascyn1(); var b =await asynci2(); task.whenall(a,b); a and b run in parallel?, if so are new threads created? If not, what happens internally?

Comment: The thread pool is a pool of threads. `Task.Run` queues the code to run on one of those threads. `a` and `b` run concurrently; asynchronous code [doesn't block a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). `WaitAll` on its own could [cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), though in this case the `Task.Run` would avoid the deadlock.

Comment: Task.Run does not create threads. Queues the thread pool to run on one of those threads. In conclusion, the task does not create threads. but if it executes the code of those tasks in one of those threads? if so then you have a bad use of resources.

Comment: @developer I'm not sure what you're saying with that comment.

Comment: maybe I was not clear in my last comment.in your comments you mentioned Task.Run doesn't create threads. Task.Run queues the code to run on one of those threads. my doubt is if it does not create threads but queues the tasks so that they are executed by one of the threads in the thread pool. then sooner or later will those tasks make use of those threads in the thread pool? If so, would you misuse the resources?

Comment: Yes, the code will eventually run on a thread pool thread. This isn't recommended because the thread pool belongs to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the `await` line the methods `GetCustomers1` and `GetCustomers2` will immediately return an incomplete task, assuming that the tasks returned from `getcustomer1Async()` and `getcustomers2Async()` are incomplete. The `await` keyword allows you to write code below the `await` line, that will run after the awaited task is completed. In your case there is no code below the await line, so you could just as well return directly the tasks without awaiting them:

```
public Task<string> GetCustomers1()
{
    return getcustomer1Async();
}
```

Notice that not only the `await` keyword is gone, but the `async` as well.

As for the `Index` method, it should give you a compile-time warning for not having an `await` inside a method marked with the `async` keyword. You should probably modify it to something like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Index()
{
   var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetCustomers1());
   var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetCustomers2());
   string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
   //...use the results to create a JsonResult and return it
}
```

Finally keep in mind that it's common practice to add the suffix `Async` to the methods that return a `Task`. So the method `GetCustomers1` should be renamed `GetCustomers1Async`, the `Index` should be renamed `IndexAsync` etc. You can read the relevant guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).